# Replace multiple occurences of the same character in between two other characters

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I replace a character only if it is present in between two specific others? Even if there is text before and after it?

For example, if I have a string like this:

```
var text = "For text `in between two backticks, replace all #es with *s`. It should `find all such possible matches for #, including multiple ### together`, but shouldn't affect ### outside backticks."
```

My desired output is:

```
"For text `in between two backticks, replace all *es with *s`. It should `find all such possible matches for *, including multiple *** together`, but shouldn't affect ### outside backticks."
```

I've got the following code:

```
text = text.replace(/`(.*?)#(.*?)`/gm, "`$1*$2`");
```

Comment: so you want to replace the `#` between two `*` ?

Comment: No, I want it to replace in between the two backticks ( ` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple `` /`[^`]+`/g `` regex that will match a backtick, then 1+ chars other than a backtick, and then again a backtick, and replace the `#` inside a callback:

```js
var text = "For text `in between two backticks, replace all #es with *s`. It should `find all such possible matches for #, including multiple ### together`, but shouldn't affect ### outside backticks.";
var res = text.replace(/`[^`]+`/g, function(m) {
  return m.replace(/#/g, '*');
});
console.log(res);
```